# How to remove horizontal line between rows in the grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml

[image]

I have two rows in the grid and there is white line which separates the rows. How to remove it ?

This is the code that i have written.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"   
    <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--First Row-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Second Row -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="#003049">
                <Button Content = "" Width= "auto" Height = "30">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @rashmatash what exactly are you trying to say ?

Comment: Did you paste the entire code of the xaml? I tried in my computed and works fine, no white line. But the first row and the second column from the second row appear in white, and there is no white line between rows. Please give us all of the code.

Comment: The issue is related background color of the window. Changing the color solved the issue. Thank you @CatarinaFerreira.